# Numpy working in iPython but not in IDE or Terminal Shell

Tags: python, shell, numpy, terminal, ipython

I am trying to create graphs to compare some statistics.

I installed NumPy through my terminal by using

```
$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Cleaning up...

$
```

When I use NumPy in iPython I am able to use graphs but when I use it in my IDE(pyCharm) or in the terminal shell I am not able to import NumPy.
I like using pyCharm because it makes my project a lot easier but this is very frustrating for me

I'm using OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Might be that your terminal and your IDE are using a different version of python. Also, most IDE has an internal definition of python path, which you sometimes need to update after installing something new.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason it isn't working because I updated to OS Mavericks lately, and that, according to other searches has caused some issues in python

I uninstalled numpy and installed it again using

$ sudo easy_install numpy

and it seems to be working now,

I am going to assume there is a similar issue going on with matplotlib